# Converting some docker-compose environment variables to secrets with jq

Tags: json, docker, docker-compose, yaml, jq

Here is my docker-compose beginning.

```
services:
  theses-api-diffusion:
    container_name: theses-api-diffusion
    environment:
      CHASSEAUXLIVRES_KEY: ?key=3a072b56267e9c3ba4b6f3ff66f7
      CHASSEAUXLIVRES_URL: http://www.chasse-aux-livres.fr/api/v1/price/
      JAVA_OPTS: -Doracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion=false -Duser.timezone=CEST
      SERVER_PORT: "8992"
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: PORTAIL
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//orpins-p-scan.v110.abes.fr:1521/THESES
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: PORTAIL
      TEL_HOSTSWORD: api.archives-ouvertes.fr
      TEL_PASSWORD: dedt@sa
      TEL_USERID: star_abes
      THESES_PATH_LOCAL: /starstock/
  theses-api-recherche:
...
```

I'd like to convert environment variables containing the word **KEY** or **PASSWORD** to a secret for each docker service, and move the **environment** to **env_file** like following:

```
services:
  theses-api-diffusion:
    cpus: 10
    container_name: theses-api-diffusion
    env_file: theses-api-diffusion.env
    secrets:
      - CHASSEAUXLIVRES_KEY
      - TEL_PASSWORD
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD
secrets:
  CHASSEAUXLIVRES_KEY:
    file: CHASSEAUXLIVRES_KEY.txt
  TEL_PASSWORD:
    file: TEL_PASSWORD.txt
  SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD:
    file: SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD.txt
```

I tried to manipulate json object with jq, and I managed to generate ''.txt'' files and to insert secrets object.

```
secrets:
  CHASSEAUXLIVRES_KEY:
    file: SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD.txt
  TEL_PASSWORD:
    file: TEL_PASSWORD.txt
  SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD:
    file: SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD.txt
```

But I failed to create the secrets for each service:

```
    secrets:
      - CHASSEAUXLIVRES_KEY
      - TEL_PASSWORD
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD
```

I could use bash commands but I do want to do such a thing with manipulating json using **jq**
Thank you for helping.

Comment: Please [edit] to include the jq you built yourself in the question, even though it didn't do everything you wanted. As it is this is basically asking folks to recreate even the parts you got working (like the string comparisons); it would be easier if you gave us code that already did the 50% you've already got, so we can focus only on the part you need help with.

Comment: That's not JSON, that's YAML. You need `yq` for that. `jq` does not support YAML input